# Return key is not handled in cell editor

Tags: mxgraph

I'm studying mxGraph examples and have the following problem. When I double-click a cell and edit in-place its content, I assume that pressing Return key should end editing and set the cell's content to the newly typed. But instead pressing the Return key works as usually in editors: it moves the caret to the new line.

Why I assume that Return should stop editing? Because comments say so (e.g. in `userobject.html`):

```
// Stops editing on enter key, handles escape
new mxKeyHandler(graph);
```

And also because there would be no convenient way to end cell editing apart from clicking with the mouse somewhere outside the cell. (By the way, Escape key is handled OK: it also ends editing, but without updating the cell content.)

This behaviour is observed in all browsers I tried: Firefox 60 on Linux, Firefox 52 and IE 11 on Windows.

Why this problem exist and how can it be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried graph.enterStopsCellEditing = true? See https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/js-api/files/view/mxGraph-js.html#mxGraph.enterStopsCellEditing